Convolution convergence in L infinity norm
Consider real valued functions f,g from a measure space of reals with the usual borel algebra. Let $p\in (1,\infty)$ and $q$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$. Suppose a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ and $g_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^q$. Show that $f_n*g_n$ converges to $f*g$ in $L^\infty$. I haven't seen how convolutions are used before, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do you know about Young's inequality?

@P.P.Tuong I haven't seen this inequality, it solves my doubt. Thanks!
